# VB6.0 MDI Spell Checker

Tags: vb6, spell-checking

I have a VB6.0 project with MDI parent and child form. Now I need to check spelling and grammar in few text boxes on that child form.

Please help with code example.

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more.

Comment: I think it is clear what Ranajit needs.

Answer (score 3):

You could license a professional **ActiveX component** like [Tachyon's spellchecker](http://www.tachyon-labs.com/tachyonspell.aspx). I found a [list here](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/titles/spell-checker-component.htm).

If you could demand **Microsoft Word** installed on the client machine as prerequisit, you could use Word's spell checker:

```
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc  As Object

Dim strResult As String

' // Create a new instance of word Application

Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")

Select Case objWord.Version
   ' // Office 2000
   Case "9.0"
      Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(, , 1, True)

   ' // Office XP
   Case "10.0"
      Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(, , 1, True)

   ' // Office 97
   Case Else ' Office 97
      Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

End Select

objDoc.Content = Text1.Text
objDoc.CheckSpelling

strResult = Left(objDoc.Content, Len(objDoc.Content) - 1)

If Text1.Text = strResult Then
    ' // There were no spelling errors, so give the user a
    ' // visual signal that something happened

    MsgBox "The spelling check is complete.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
End If
```

You can find another good example in this article about how to [call the MS Word Spell Checker](http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/spellcheck.aspx).

Comment: This codes work just fine except for the fact that it looses all the previous formatting of the text box. Kindly advice.