# How to Use OpenOffice.org Spell Checker in My App (VB6)

Tags: vb6, openoffice.org, spell-checking

It is possible to [use Microsoft Word to spell chek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214805/vb6-0-mdi-spell-checker) an arbitrary document.

What I want is to use OpenOffice.org to do the same.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OpenOffice Developer's Guide is [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide).

OpenOffice has COM bindings which you can read about [here](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge).

The API reference is [here](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/module-ix.html)

The l[inguistic2](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/linguistic2/module-ix.html) module is what you interested in and has documentation on the [spell checker](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/linguistic2/SpellChecker.html).

My opinion that it is rather involved to get this going and only of use if you are planning to have OpenOffice as part of your solution. I would look at the various 3rd party offering for VB6 and spell checking.

Answer (score 0):

Its not very likely. OpenOffice is written in Java and you want to use VB6. Unless you can find a Java->VB6 bridge it won't happen very effecently. [relatively (bridges aren't known for their speed)]

Comment: What if was working with Java. Does OpenOffice.org provides a way to use his internal spell checker?

Comment: I have no idea about this. There is Java code within their project to use this. Worse case senario you could strip it out. Best case (which is most likely) they seperated the functionality into a component.

Comment: @Daniel: There are OpenOffice-Bindings for Mono and I think I've seen some for Python, so I'm very sure that there are bindings for Java, too.

Answer (score 0):

Google turns up this article [showing how to use the OpenOffice spellchecker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/OOSpellCheck.aspx?msg=2807793) from C#.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this (or actually read the whole article).

You could write a [COM-visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186640/create-com-component-and-activex-controls-in-net-c-and-net-framework-3-5) C# (or VB.Net) component, and call it from VB6.